# How to upgrade iOS Core Data model and data

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I've got an iOS app which uses Core Data (SQLite on the backend). It only has one entity, 'Item'. There is a SQLite file bundled with the app, with hundreds of items pre-added, so when the user downloads the app from the App Store it already has the data.

The only entity has a `BOOL favorite` attribute which the user can alter, used -of course- to check if an item is among the user favorite items.

I'm planning to publish an update of the app with **more items pre-built** in the app bundle (a new SQLite file), but I want to **keep the user favorites**. As well, in this version my Core Data model will suffer a few modifications (I need some new properties in the 'Item' entity). The new set of items is a superset of the old items (an item in the old version of the app **shall** be in the new version, always).

I've been struggling with this a lot and I can't find a solution to this. I'm able to upgrade the data model introducing new properties into my entity while keeping the user favorites (performing a so-called *lightweight migration*, but then I'm not able to merge old and new items. On the other hand, I'm able to get the new pre-added items, but then the favorite-related data is discarded.

Any hint? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem.

I've got two NSPersistentStoreCoordinators, two NSManagedObjectContexts and two NSManagedObjectModels in my app delegate: one set to use in the application (the updated one) and another set pointing to the old store. In my app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method I load all the user's favorites from the old store and save them into the new one. That's the only point in the app where I touch the old store.

Thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a second database with your new stuff in there, but without favorites. Then you pull favorites from your old database and insert them into your new one. Remove the old database and replace with the new one. That seems like the most straight-forward solution. There may be functionality built into Core Data for these situations, but chances are this is easier.

Comment: Thank you @Scott for your quick response. That's what I have in mind, but I'd like to know how could I do that following in a Core Data native fashion.

Comment: Please post some code on how you currently set up your database.

Comment: My app follows exactly the steps described here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html (sign in required)